# Why can't I have WPA handshake on aircrack?

Tags: wpa2

I know this might seems general question to be googled first and I have tried.

I have successfully de-authenticated the client or clients multiple times but I didn't get the message of `WPA handshake` but in it's place (top right corner) is written: `fixed channel mon0:-1`.

Also I should mention I followed procedure as given on Aircrack website.

Comment: A few things: 1) it would be helpful to actually have screenshots, 2) it would also be helpful if you listed the command sequence you used, and 3) we really aren't tech support - there's too many possible issues that could be involved

Comment: Started monitoring-airmon-ng start wlan0,start airodump-airodump-ng -c channel --bssid 00:**:6C:&^:40:80 -w psk mon0 at mon0 then deauth the client using aireplay-ng -0 10 -a 00:**:6C:7E:40:80 -c 00:0F:**:FD:FB:C2 mon0 results were successful many ACK work but no message like wpa handshake : bssid

Comment: Actually i dont know how to add screenshot here.

Comment: Please edit your question to include those details. When you edit you will see the button to include images

Comment: Have you searched online for the message you're getting? I'm seeing a lot of great fixes for this problem.

Comment: the answer to your question is detailed on [askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/318583/how-can-i-solve-fixed-channel-1-mon0-is-on-channel-1-issue-when-using-airo)

Comment: @Rust To add pictures to a post there is an "image" button to the right of the "bold" and "italics" buttons just above the box you type in.

Answer (score 0):

The message "fixed channel mon0:-1" usually means there are some problems with the compat-wireless package. Try to install the newer version using the following instructions:

http://aircrack-ng.org/doku.php?id=compat-wireless